# Using mpz_t as key for std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, gmp

I am trying to build a map from `mpz_t` keys to `uint` values. I don't know why but the `mpz_t` keys can somehow not be looked up in the map.

```
mpz_t leftSideValues[1 << 20];

int main()
{
    std::map<mpz_t, uint> leftSide;

    for (uint i = 0; i < 1 << 20; i++)
    {
        mpz_init(leftSideValues[i]);

        // compute some stuff here...

        // now save the computed value to our map
        leftSide[leftSideValues[i]] = i;

        // do a lookup to see whether our value can be found
        std::cout << leftSide.at(leftSideValues[i]) << " -- " << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output would be a lot of lines looking like "0 -- 0", "1 -- 1" etc. but that does not happen. Instead:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  map::at
```

Is there some other step that I need to take to make `mpz_t` be usable in a map?

Comment: When I try to compile with a recent version of clang++ instead of g++, I get many compilation errors. It seems that `mpz_t` is a typedef of a type that can't be used as key in `std::map`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What criteria does a key type have to fulfill to be eligible for use in a map? Looking at http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Internals.html#Integer-Internals it seems that `mpz_t` is just some sort of `struct`. Can those not be used as key type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4254906/1401351

Comment: That won't work. Try going for `mpz_class` instead or write your own C++ wrapper class. `mpz_t` is just some C struct that won't play nice with C++ containers, just because there is **no** overloaded '<' operator for it, which is **required** by `std::map`: ["This defaults to less<T>, which returns the same as applying the less-than operator (a<b)."](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/). If you are feeling creative, implement your own operator overload, or use the custom comparer that you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `map` cannot compare two `mpz_t` instances.

According to [the C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) maps are implemented as binary search trees. Therefore if elements cannot be compared search is impossible.

Adding a comparer fixed this problem:

```
struct mpzCompare
{
    bool operator() (const mpz_t val1, const mpz_t val2) const
    {
        return mpz_cmp(val1, val2) > 0;
    }
};

std::map<mpz_t, uint, mpzCompare> leftSide;
```